# how to merge two different List objects into one List and sort them

Tags: java

i want to merge two different List objects into another List and i have to sort them.
I have classes like below

class Employee and Class Staff both classes implements the Comparable and sorting based on timestamp which is long value

```
List<Employee> empList=new ArrayList<>();
    List<Staff> staffList=new ArrayList<>();
    Employee emp1=new Employee(3, "EPPI CF", 1507542925000l);
    Employee emp2=new Employee(2, "EPPI CF2", 1507542924000l);
    Employee emp3=new Employee(1, "EPPI CF3", 1507543156000l);
    empList.add(emp1);
    empList.add(emp2);
    empList.add(emp3);
    Collections.sort(empList);
    Staff staff1=new Staff(1, "Parnamya", 1507724760000l);
    Staff staff2=new Staff(2, "Sreenu", 1507623378000l);
    Staff staff3=new Staff(3, "Joseph", 1507621774000l);
    Staff staff4=new Staff(4, "Dolores", 1507547700000l);
    Staff staff5=new Staff(5, "Molly", 1507541100000l);
    staffList.add(staff1);
    staffList.add(staff2);
    staffList.add(staff3);
    staffList.add(staff4);
    staffList.add(staff5);
    Collections.sort(staffList);
    List<Object> allObj=new ArrayList<>();
    allObj.addAll(empList);
    allObj.addAll(staffList);
```

i want to sort final list which is allObj based on timestamp(long value) in both the objects common property is timestamp.

how can i do this?

Expected output:

```
[Staff [id=1, staffName=Parnamya, timestamp=1507724760000],
Staff [id=2, staffName=Sreenu, timestamp=1507623378000], 
Staff [id=3, staffName=Joseph, timestamp=1507621774000],
Staff [id=4, staffName=Dolores,timestamp=1507547700000],
[
    Employee [id=1, name=EPPI CF3, timstamp=1507543156000], 
    Employee [id=3, name=EPPI CF, timstamp=1507542925000], 
    Employee [id=2, name=EPPI CF2, timstamp=1507542924000],
    Staff [id=5, staffName=Molly, timestamp=1507541100000]
]
```

Comment: But do `Employee` and `Staff` share a common interface? If not then you'll find it difficult to create a comparator which can compare one type with the other.

Comment: Hi Bobulous thankyou for the reply. I didn't get your question, both the classes are implementing the Comparable interface.

Comment: @user3355101 yes, but can you compare an `Employee` to a `Staff`?

Comment: Is `Employee` a subclass of `Staff`? If so, important to note in your Question. If not, you cannot be adding `Employee` objects to a `List` of type `Staff` and your example code is broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make them extend the same super class or implement the same interface to compare. Having them both extend a class like the following should work:

```
public abstract class TimeStamped implements Comparable<TimeStamped>{

@Override
public int compareTo(TimeStamped timedObject) {
    return Long.compare(this.getTimeStamp(), timedObject.getTimeStamp());
}

public abstract long getTimeStamp();

}
```

Comment: Oh nice call on the long compare, didn't know that existed. By null check, do you mean an if statement to check that timedObject isn't null? If that's the case I'm not sure if you would want to continue with the comparison.

Comment: Yeah, forget about `null`, my mistake, it should and will throw `NullPointerException`

Comment: Hi lickydog32 thankyou for the answer. I tried with above solution getting the below output 
[Employee [id=1, name=EPPI CF3, timstamp=1507543156000], Employee [id=3, name=EPPI CF, timstamp=1507542925000], Employee [id=2, name=EPPI CF2, timstamp=1507542924000], Staff [id=1, staffName=Parnamya, timestamp=1507724760000], Staff [id=2, staffName=Sreenu, timestamp=1507623378000], Staff [id=3, staffName=Joseph, timestamp=1507621774000], Staff [id=4, staffName=Dolores,timestamp=1507547700000], Staff [id=5, staffName=Molly, timestamp=1507541100000]] but expected output updated in the Question

Comment: Are you using TimeStamped as your generic upper bound for your new list? Like: `List<TimeStamped> allObj=new ArrayList<>();` And then sorting after?

Comment: No, added and tried its working. Thankyou very much  @luckydog32